# Put Current Post's URL in Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to put URL of the current post in a textarea on each post so I typed following code in the post editor (HTML mode):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var postUrl = '<data:post.url/>';
  document.write('<textarea>');
  document.write(postUrl);
  document.write('</textarea>');
</script>
```

But what appeared was

```
<data:post.url/>
```

which is not replaced by the post URL.

The layout HTML contains following code:

```
<body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
```

Since there are many custom Facebook/Twitter widgets ('like' button, etc) available, I think there must be some way to pass the *value* of data:post.url to target jscript, but my googling failed.

Comment: this code wont work in widgets..blogger API mostly works on the default template...u putting this in template right?

Comment: No i'm planning to put the script in each post. Before that I tried document.write(document.url); but document.url is just the URL of the blog.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge,it wont work in posts...blogger tags work only and only in templates,not posts/widgets.

Answer (score 2):

You could put this in your post:

```
<div id="mytextbox"></div>
```

Then edit your template by putting this code at the bottom before the `</body>` closing tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var d=document;
var mydiv = d.getElementById(&quot;mytextbox&quot;);
if (mydiv!=null)
{
mydiv.innerHTML = mydiv.innerHTML + &quot;<textarea>&quot;+&quot;<data:blog.url/>&quot;+&quot;</textarea>&quot;;
}
</script>
```

Blogger layout code `<data:blog.url/>` actually returns The URL of the current page, not the URL of the blog.

Comment: thanks but data:blog.url gives only blog URL, not the URL of each post

Comment: I tried the code in my blog and it returns blog post URL. For more information about Blogger Layout Elements read this: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270#global where it says "url: The URL of the current page.","homepageUrl: The homepage of the blog."

Comment: if I clicked the title of a post, then the URL get changed, and the textarea shows the correct (post-specific) URL. Then using data:blog.url is just the same as document.write(document.url)?

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. If you want to put URL of the posts in the home page, then you should use data:post.url but you will probably have to locate the piece of code in the template that loops through the posts

Comment: Can you be more specific? :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's just treating 'data:post.url' as a string since it's surrounded by quotes, does this work?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.write('<textarea>' + data:post.url + '</textarea>');
</script>
```

Comment: This puts nothing to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use check below script, which is working for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var postUrl = '<data:post.url/>';
     document.write("<div class="fb-like" data-href='" + postUrl + "' data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>");
</script>
```

Its give link of each post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need javascript to do that. You only need to specify a value using expr:value like this:

```
<input type="text" expr:value='data:blog.url'/>
```

You can then style it however you want by using inline style like this:

```
    <input type="text" expr:value='data:blog.url' style='height:30px; width:100px;' />
```

To ensure that you have the link in the right place, you must inspect the elements of the blog page carefully and paste the code in the desired location.

Hope that helps.